# Angular modular application best practices

Tags: angularjs, module, gruntjs

My folder structure :

```
 /app 
   /components 
       /module1 
       /module2
       /core 
          /extensions
             -array.js
             -string.js
          /services
             -localdataservice.js 
          /directives 
             - .... .js
   index.html
```

each file aside from it's essence is associated with an angular module 'app.core'
for example : array.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var core = angular.module(app.core, []);
    core.config( function(){

    if (!Array.prototype.last){
        Array.prototype.last = function(){
            return this[this.length - 1];
        };
     }; 
   })
}());
```

Composing all of these files and there contents under a usable module as some fallbacks.

1) Only one file can create the module and the rest need to use the module and add on to it.

```
   meaning that all other files then the arbitrarly chosen array.js would use the module as :

   var core = angular.app('app.core');  
      and not 
   var core = angular.app('app.core',[]);
```

2) I would have to reference each file from index.html in order for it to take part in the module's initiation.

index.html

```
  <html> 
    <body>

        <script src="components/core/array.js"></script>
        <script src="components/core/string.js"></script>
        <script src="components/core/localdataserice.js"></script>
        .... and many more 
    </body> 
</html>
```

There must be a better way for building a module across multiple files. 
at first i thought about copying all of the contents of the files under a seperate file

```
/app 
  /components 
     /core
        /lib
          -core.js
```

index.html

```
<html> 
    <body>

        <script src="components/core/lib/core.js"></script>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I thought of doing this with a grunt copy task. but that would require me to somehow manipulate the process of the copy task the fit content under the IFFE wrapper and the angular's module initiation.

```
 (function() {
    'use strict';

     var core = angular.module(app.core, []);
     core.config( function(){
           ... ALL THE FILES CONTENTS GO HERE 

      })
   }());
```

And again there's gotta be a better way. 
any suggestions ?

**EDIT :**

I decided to try **Browserify** along with **Grunt** and **grunt-browserify**

Gruntfile.js

```
 grunt.initConfig({
     browserify :{
        main: {
           src: 'app/components/core/{,*/}*.js',  
           dest: 'app/components/core/lib/core'
        }
      }
 });
```

For this example the build file only has the content of **array.js**

```
 (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){

     if (!Array.prototype.last){
          Array.prototype.last = function(){
            return this[this.length - 1];
        };
    };
 },{}]},{},[1]);
```

1) What i don't understand is how can i incorporate an export function in it. 
since i wan't to require it from other modules.

```
 module.exports = function() {
   // Your code 
 }
```

2) Iv'e seen no reference in any tutorials on that weird looking wrapper my code was placed in. not sure what it does maybe it as an export in there some where :/

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide for a great place to start. one thing that stands out from your post - no need to create a variable to reference your app module. This way, you access your angular module by the get method - `angular.module('app')` or whatever you want to call it, and you can modularize your code much better, allowing you to simple concat your js library files into one build file, so you don't have 100 script tags in your html as your app grows.

Comment: yes but that's the fallbacks i mentioned.  i don't wan't to call angular.module and wrap each of them in an iffe and the copy then all along with it. 
what if i wanted that code to be purely Javascript and have nothing to do with angular.

Comment: Have you checked out browserify? You would simply export functions with no need for IIFE's.

Comment: @AnidMonsur i'll check that out

Comment: generator-gulp-angular does me well... inserts all the development files in index.html and ties into browsersynch for live updates. Doesn't care about directory structure much either

Comment: @AnidMonsur when using browserify the idea is to copy all the files into one file like core.js and then run browserify on it ?

Comment: @AnidMonsur i edited the question, would you mind having a look ?